# App react-native works locally but can't generate APK (ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries)

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, apk

When running the gradlew bundleRelease command to generate the APK I get the following error at the prompt:

```
C:\Users\natha\OneDrive\Documentos\WorkspaceNathan\mob-t\gvpmobile\android>gradlew bundleRelease

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Android gradle plugin: 7.3.1
Gradle: 7.5.1
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

**Has codes in the middle**

  ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
139 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 132 up-to-date
```

**My android/app/build.gradle file is showing the following error in the image:**

[android/app/build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0RrZ.png)

**My node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle file is showing the following errors in the images:**

[node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw8eO.png)

[node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ohxt.png)

[node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujJMg.png)

**When I run npx react-native run-android to run the app on the emulator it works normally with the following WARNING:**

[Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Hqo.png)

**I've tried several approaches to generate the APK but I couldn't, I'm using version 0.71 of React-native without typescript in the project.**

**Below I leave my package.json file to inform the versions of the dependencies:**

```
{
  "name": "gvpmobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.2",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**I built an app with react-native that works running locally on the emulator but doesn't allow me to generate the APK with the gradlew bundleRelease command. I need to generate this APK to upload the app to the Play Store.**

**The keystore key has already been generated.**

Comment: Were you able to solve This?